# SQL select max items by grouping on department

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table `mytable` with `name, department, rating`

**example:**

```
a, d1, 3
b, d1, 5
c, d1, 10
a1, d2, 4
a2, d2, 1
a3, d2, 5
```

I want the output to group the output by department and pick the one with highest rating and display like this:

```
c, d1, 10
a3, d2, 5
```

I tried like this:

```
select name, department, max(rating) from mytab
group by department.
```

But this query is wrong as I need to add name also to group by clause. What is the right way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the records with max rating within a department, so if two have the max rating, you will see both.

In the subquery you get the max values per department and then you just select all records with that value

```
select mytable.*
FROM  mytable
   JOIN (SELECT department, MAX(rating) AS rating 
         FROM mytable 
         GROUP BY department) maxvals
   USING (department, rating)
```

Comment: what is the use of `Using` keyword and how it works?

Comment: Dear learner, to learn basics, Google is faster than asking . ;)

Comment: @learner - `FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING(a,b)` is a shorthand for `FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b)`